# Can buffing and sanding attachments be used with a fixed speed powerdrill?

Tags: drill, powertools, sanding, cutting

Have wondered about this possibility. I've seen some 'As seen on TV' ads where they sell all-in-one DIY power-tool kits which can act as a drill (reversible), power screw in/unscrew, hammer, buffing, sanding and even cutting tool.

Are such attachments available for regular consumer-grade power drills, and are they effective, or even semi-effective (in the 'your mileage may vary' sense) ?

Note that this is only for some occasional use, by a DIY hobbyist. Not for professional grade work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, but not as effectively as a purposefully designed tool. Take a look at buffing and sanding tools' RPM. It's significantly higher than that of a power drill: 8,000 - 15,000 for an air powered palm sander vs 300-1,500 RPM for a standard variable speed drill.

Other aspects depend upon the modular design of the particular tool you're interested in. For example, a simple rotary sander will leave circular scratches in wood that a random orbital sander will not. These scratches become very evident when stain is applied.

Power is another factor. Purpose-built tools are designed to provide peak power in their application range. A multi-purpose do-it-all tool will likely compromise this "tuning" to be able to work in all applications.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, tool kits like this do exist outside of the gimmicky "As-Seen-On-TV" ads. The [Ridgid Jobmax](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007O2WM6C) is one example, and the [Black & Decker Matrix](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009VK6G8U) is another.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean by fixed speed powerdrill? There's hammer drills and then there's rotary hammers. Most hammer drills use chucks, much like any a regular drill (albiet they have an additional means to be tightened. Rotary hammers use SDS bits, differing slightly from one another based on the brand. You can use a chuck adapter for a rotary hammer like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-SDS-Chuck-Adapter-Kit-48-66-1370/202905997). As far as I'm aware, sanding and buffing attachments connect to normal chuck adapters.